# String Manipulation: Taking numbers out of a string in java?

Tags: java, string, ping

I want to be able to extract certain things from strings such as numbers, what is the most efficient way to perform this action in terms of both speed and accuracy?

So for example if I have a file: PingFile.txt where its contents are just the ping of a server piped in like:

```
PING google.com (74.125.224.46): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 74.125.224.46: icmp_seq=0 ttl=45 time=5.134 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.224.46: icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=5.102 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.224.46: icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=5.062 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.224.46: icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=4.988 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.224.46: icmp_seq=4 ttl=45 time=5.368 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.224.46: icmp_seq=5 ttl=45 time=5.012 ms
```

If I wanted to extract only the time values(5.134, 5.102, 5.062, etc) and then parse them floats or doubles instead of the strings they are. how would I do this?

Thanks,

Euden

Comment: Have you started writing the code yet?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Define "best way". Are you looking for speed, readability or something else?

Comment: Open your file using a `Scanner` or a `BufferedFileReader`. Read line by line and search the pattern you want/need using a Regular Expression. You can find regex pattern for IP on internet, [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) is a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that for each line :

```
String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
String timeString = tokens[tokens.length-2];
float time = Float.parseFloat(timeString);
```

If needed, you may use a BufferedReader to read line after line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `regex="time=[0-9\\.]+"` to find the String as `time=5.134` and `time=5.102`

Then do a substring as `"time=5.134".substring(5)` to get the number part.

Code sample below:

```
String timeString = "64 bytes from 74.125.224.46: icmp_seq=0 ttl=45 time=5.134 ms";
Pattern timePattern = Pattern.compile("time=[0-9\\.]+");
Matcher timeMatcher = timePattern.matcher(timeString);
if(timeMatcher.find()){
    String timeS = timeMatcher.group(0);
    System.out.println(timeS);
    String time = timeS.substring(5);
    System.out.println(time);
    double t = Double.parseDouble(time);
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of ways to do it, like...

- using the Pattern class, but that's probably very heavyweight for what you want
- using the Scanner class, though that may still be more than you need
- using string.split(" ")[6], and Float.valueOf() (or Double.valueOf())

I'm sure there's other ways to do it, too.